# Convert a single-threaded calculation to multi-threaded in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, maps

I have a situation where my code needs to do to huge calculation for each "fund" in a list.

I can do it in sequential order and it works perfectly fine, however it takes lot of time. For 1 fund it takes about 13-15 minuntes. I have to run this for 50+ funds and it take huge amount of time.

The code snippet is something like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> fundsList = getTheListOfFunds()
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> itr = fundsList.listIterator();
List<Map<String, Object>> expectedDataList = new ArrayList<>();
while (itr.hasNext()) { 
    Map<String, Object> finalData = doCalc(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
    expectedDataList.add(finalData);
}
```

I am very new to multi-threading. Can someone please help me to refactor the code so that the calculation (`doCalc`) can be done in multiple threads instead of a single thread?

Comment: @Brajesh Look into `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and `java.util.concurrent.Future`. A method that might work for you is `ExecutorService#invokeAll(List<Callable<T>>)`.

Comment: Thank you  @Slaw let me dig more onto ExecutorService. This is something i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) method to get an ExecutorService to submit tasks to.

Each task that you submit to the thread pool will return a `Future`, which you can maintain a list of and retrieve the returned value at a later time.

Here's an example:

```java
// Create a new fixed thread pool with a predefined number of threads.
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

// Create a list of Future objects to retrieve later.
List<Future<Map<String, Object>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

// Loop through your list and for each iteration, submit your task
// to the Executor service, and add the result to your Future list.
for (Map<String, Object> fund: fundsList) {
    futures.add(service.submit(() -> doCalc(/* parameters */)));
}

// Loop through the Future list and call the .get() method to
// retrieve the computed value.
for (Future<Map<String, Object>> future: futures) {
    try {
        final Map<String, Object> finalData = future.get();
        expectedDataList.add(finalData);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // log or throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: I was typing up a response, and this popped in right before I submitted.  It is more elegant that what I typed so I give it a thumbs up.

I would check that all the Futures are done (future.isDone()) before retrieving the values.  Basically, you don't grab anything until the last guy is done.  But that's me...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and comments. Special thanks to @blacktide and @federOnline for putting us in the right direction. I work with Brajesh and here is what we wrote, please correct us for any issues.

```java
public class MyThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        // Create a list of Future objects to retrieve later.
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        // Loop through your list and for each iteration, submit your task
        // to the Executor service, and add the result to your Future list.
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            futures.add(service.submit(() -> add(a[finalI], b[finalI])));
        }

        // Loop through the Future list and call the .get() method to
        // retrieve the computed value.
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Future<Integer> future: futures) {
            try {
                 int finalData = future.get();
                 if(future.isDone()) {
                     list.add(finalData);
                 }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // log or throw error
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list.size());
        service.shutdown();
    }

    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return a + b;
    }
}
```